# prove that $f(z) =(z^2 -a^2)^{1/2}$ has a continuous branch.

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

We can consider $g(z)= e^{\frac{1}{2}(\log(z-a)+\log(z+a))}$
to prove this function is a branch. Should I prove first that it is continuous then its derivative is $f(z)$?

Comment: Your title uses $A$ while your function uses lower case $a.$ Pick one.

Comment: all are small case

Comment: What do ou mean by "the function is branch?"

Comment: Well, no they are not. But if you mean them to be the same case, you can edit the question to make them the same.